# How to use root motion with inverse kinematics?

Tags: animation, inverse-kinematics, unreal-engine

I have created a simple attack animation using inverse kinematics to animate the arms and legs of a character. Now, I want the animation to use root motion to export it to Unreal Engine 4.

I have watched multiple tutorials that explain how to do this with a Mixamo animation. I understand that I have to copy the location keyframes of the hips to my root bone and then remove them from the hips.

This would work perfectly if not for the fact that I am using inverse kinematics. If my IK bones have no parents, the animation looks great, but I can't export the fbx since Unreal will detect multiple root bones. However, if I parent the IK bones to the root bone, it will offset the limbs' positions and mess up the animation.

I'm wondering if there is a way to remove the IK bones without affecting the position of the limbs, so I can export the animation correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bake your action into a new action clearing all constarints, so the animation will act the same movements without the need of IK.

To do so, select in pose mode all deforming bones, and go to the menu:"Pose - Animation - Bake Action".

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much, I was losing my mind over this.