# Keyframe non IK bones

Tags: animation, rigging, inverse-kinematics

I've created a somewhat working IK rig for a video game character that I would want to animate for use in the game through modding.

My issue is that when I move my IK bones and set a key frame for all the bones, the ones that are moved by the IK only have a solid line in the dope sheet indicating that nothing has changed, so they stay still when exported and imported into the game for the character to use.
[image]

Is there a way to keyframe bones that are moved by IK bones?

Edit: This seems to work
[How to use root motion with inverse kinematics?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151002/how-to-use-root-motion-with-inverse-kinematics/151063#151063)

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151002/how-to-use-root-motion-with-inverse-kinematics/151063#151063

Comment: Thank you!
That seems to have worked, too bad my rig has unrelated issues making it incompatible.