# Rigid Body Issues (Chain is passing through object and not following the mesh)

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I created a simulation setup where chains fall on the object and the object moves and physically the chain should move along but it is not happening so. The chain stays there and the object moves away.

[image: https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-b7f6f0788bd7.gif]

Comment: This might be what you're trying to achieve except the slap is moving down and not across... - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154838/rigidbody-change-dynamic-simulation-to-animatic/154886#154886 - If no good, leave a comment and I'll get back.

Comment: Well that's a different case, in my case, there are a lot of chain elements which are being simulated with physics too and then they have to collide with the object underlying and then they all must follow him. It is an experiment to check if the things work, I want to attach this chain to a human and make it react to his body when he is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example uses the same arrangement mentioned in my comments above in that the falling object is parented to another which is to drag it along (or down) with it.   It's been done in Vers 2.77a. (Blend file below)

[image]

With this one, a necklace wouldn't be rigid when it lands, so it's best to keep the array and curve modifier's active so both can be adjusted to emulate real world physics. i.e. deform the necklace's curve.

Soft-body physics etc. can be tried but for this sort of job emulating physics with a few simple keyframes and hooks is arguably more effective and efficient.

To begin with, a circle curve in Edit mode has just 4 control points.  Intermediate CP's can be added by selecting two adjacent points and using "Subdivide". (press W)  Reshape the necklace as necessary at frame 1.

Six CP's are used here.  Nth, East, Sth & West, with two subdivides, SE & SW.

If it's going to be noticed, the chain's array modifier's link offset-value, will need minute adjustment via a keyframe when the array comes to rest.  This will prevent an overlapping link appearing at the array's original starting link.

Animate the hooks to deform the curve-circle and emulate physics.  The Graph editor makes this a relatively simple task, reshaping each hook's curves accordingly.  (See the Blend file -> Graph Editor)

-============-

The large circle-empty designated "Nav" (navigation), parents everything involved with the necklace. i.e. the original array, the curve circle, and hooks, to keep it all together.  The 'Nav' in turn is parented to the bust.

It's the Nav-empty that's keyframed to take the whole thing down initially, and on impact the hooks take over to deform the necklace's curve-modifier.  The bust when moved, takes the whole thing with it.

You would do the same thing when the bust (or character) is moving about, simply deform the necklace's curve to suit and emulate physics once more.

If you're looking to the physics engine to do it all for you as a game engine might, I'm not sure that would be practical in Blender.

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks alot for your great effort in this, but the file which you sent me have the objects kinda locked, I cant select them to see it properly.
But what I have got is that you added hook modifiers to the curve and then added the rigid body to that ones so that they can move according to the gravity and collide with the mesh?

Comment: I can be a tad clumsy at times so I lock things down!  To undo that, hover over the Outliner and press 'HOME'.  Everything with dependencies will be expanded.  Hold the left MB over the first shaded arrow and drag the pointer down.  All arrows you travel over will be reactivated and their objects accessible again.  Some may have the eye & camera icons shaded also.  You'll also need those on to access.

Comment: Your second question - I'm going on memory now (not on the big machine) but I don't think I used physics at all, just emulated gravity and physics with keyframes on the hooks to deform the curve.  There was no 'Rigid body' as such, just a 2-link chain, arrayed and sized to become a necklace.